# Parse sees only first element from array in Android

Tags: android, arrays, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as my backend, and I want to download data from server. I have tags which filter these data. Unfortunately it works wrong. Lets say I have two tags "city1" and "city2", now I only get data for "city1".

```
public ArrayList<Dataset> getDatasetFromServer(Context context) {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Dataset");
    List<String> cities = DatabaseAdapter.getCityNames(context);
    //cities list contains "city1" and "city2"
    query.whereContainedIn("cities", Arrays.asList(cities.toArray(new String[cities.size()])));
    ArrayList<Dataset> dataset = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        List<ParseObject> parseDataset = query.find();
        dataset = setDatasetList(parseDataset);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return dataset;
}
```

The problem is with this : `Arrays.asList(cities.toArray(new String[cities.size()])`.
Don't know why, but this convertion works wrong with `Parse`. 
However, if I change above line to this

```
String[] array = {"city1", "city2"};
query.whereContainedIn("cities", Arrays.asList(array));
```

Everything works fine and I get data for city1 and city2.
My question is, what's the difference between these two solutions and how to fix this so the first solution works?

EDIT :
This also doesn't work :

```
query.whereContainedIn("cities", DatabaseAdapter.getCityNames(context));
```

`getCityNames` returns `List<String>`

Comment: Log what the following outputs: DatabaseAdapter.getCityNames()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of converting your list to an array and then back to a list, just do this:

```
query.whereContainedIn("cities", cities);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was my fault. Both solutions work good. 
The reason it didn't worked was that my method 
`DatabaseAdapter.getCityNames(context)` put a whitespace on the beggining of second element which I didn't saw.